# Gentelella UI framework issue with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, gentelella

I was trying to integrate Gentelella Bootstrap Admin template (https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/gentelella) but bump to an issue with jquery dependencies. Error: 'JQuery is not defined'.

[image: JQuery is not defined]
I wonder if anybody ever tried to implement such a thing and has done it successfully. Please share with me if you did. Thank you.

I have make sure to follow all the required steps from the articles here:

> https://libraries.io/github/shenshuai89/vueGentelella
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/gentelella
>   https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/gentelella/issues/729

but none helped.

```
    import 'jquery';
    import 'popper.js';
    import 'bootstrap';
    import 'gentelella/vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick';
    import 'gentelella/vendors/nprogress/nprogress';
    import 'gentelella';
    import Vue from "vue";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import router from "./router";
    import store from "./store";
    import "./registerServiceWorker";

    Vue.config.productionTip = false;

    require('gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    require('gentelella/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    require('gentelella/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css');
    require('gentelella/build/css/custom.min.css');

    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably answer this myself, fortunately I have found a git repository that had successfully integrate Gentelella framework with Vue.js. Thanks.
Source: https://github.com/shenshuai89/vueGentelella